# Filter duplicates from a list in Python

Tags: python, filter

I'm given a problem where I have to filter out dupes from a list such a

```
a = [1,1,4,5,6,5]
```

This is my code:

```
def unique(a):
    uni = []
    for value in a:
        if value[0] not in found:
            yield value
            found.add(value[0])
            print list(unique(a))
```

However, when I define the list, `a`, and try `unique(a)`, I get this output:

```
<generator object unique at 0x0000000002891750>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I get the list?

EDIT, NEW PROBLEM..
I was able to get it print out the filtered list, but I lose the order of the list. 
How can I prevent this?

```
def unique(a):
        s = set()
        for i in a:
            if i not in s:
                s.add(i)
        return s
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: If you want to preserve order, first put all the duplicates in a set or list, then create an empty result list and add all the non-duplicated elements you encounter to it while traversing the original list sequentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep track of all the elements that have been seen. The best way is to use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as lookup complexity of it is `O(1)`.

```
>>> def unique(it):
        s = set()
        for el in it:
            if el not in s:
                s.add(el)
                yield el


>>> list(unique(a))
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you don't need to keep the order of the elements you can utilize the `set` constructor, and then convert it back to list. This will remove all the duplicates, but will destroy the order of the elements:

```
list(set(a))
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get "<generator object unique at 0x0000000002921678>"

i'm also required to get the answer just by inputting "unique(a)"

Comment: i tried adding print list(unique(a)) and i get the error, but when I input list(unique(a)), it prints out the list fine...

Comment: @user1730056 What version of Python do you use?

Comment: @user1730056 You use `unique` inside `unique`, which causes the problems. Use it out of `unique` block.

Comment: Using `yield` makes your function a generator-creator.  Calling it will return a generator.  This generator can be used in various ways, the simplest being using `list(generator)` to make a list out of the elements the generator yields.  Another very common use is using `for element in generator: ...` .  You might want to use it this way instead of just using `print generator` .

Comment: @user1730056 You in your code use `yield`. It does all the magic to return values. And you have only to print them out. So you can use `list` on `unique` or just iterate through it with `for` and print all  the values.

Comment: @user1730056 Look this [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) to get the idea of how iterators and generators work.

Comment: it's working, thank you very much.
one problem I still have, is that im required to type in unique(a), not list(unique(a)) inorder to get the filtered list. 

i tried doing print list(unique(a)). i tried removing yield and trying to return, but when I do that, i dont get the list in the same order that it was

Comment: @user1730056 try this: `for i in unique(a): print(i)`. `print(i)` should be on the new line indented.

Comment: I figured out why I wasn't able to return, but now I lost my retained order

Comment: @user1730056 I can't understand what you want :) But when you understand how iterators and generators work, everything else will become very easy and straightforward.

Comment: sorry for being unclear
let's say my list was a = [5,2,7,5,4], the output my teacher wants is [5,2,7,4]. but using the return method, I get [2,4,5,7]

Comment: @user1730056 In your new question you create a `set` `s` and add the elements to it. And finally return this set `s`. But `set` is **unordered**. So `s` doesn't keep order of the elements.

Comment: @user1730056 Please, read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators). After that you should try to understand every line of the code in my answer. Then everything will be clear. Now you make an impression that you don't quite understand what you are doing. (if you don't understand, how would computer do that? :) ).

Comment: @user1730056 Iterators and generators are the fundamental things of Python and they form the core of it. They are very important to understand. If you understand them, the rest will become 10 times clear.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to remove duplicates, use a set:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5]
>>> set(a)
{1, 4, 5, 6}
>>> list(set(a)) # if you really _need_ a list, you can convert it back
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Second, the output you get, `generator object unique at 0x...`, means that you have a generator object, instead of a simple list as its return value. And this is what you should expect after using `yield` in the function. `yield` will make any function a generator and will give you only all results, if you request them (or iterate over it). If you just want to get the full result, you can call `list()` on the object to create a list from the generator object: `list(unique(a))`.

However, then you will notice the errors your function gives you: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. The reason for that is the `value[0]` you use. `value` is an element from the list (you iterate over the list) and as such is an integer. You cannot get the first element from the integer, so you probably meant just `value` there.

Next, you add elements to `found` although you defined the list as `uni` first, so you should decide on one of the names there. Also, the method is `append`, not `add`.

Finally, you should really not recursively call the method with the same parameter multiple times inside the function again, as this will just fill up the stack without providing any use, so remove the print out of it.

Then, you end up with this, which works just fine:

```
>>> def unique(a):
        found = [] # better: use a set() here
        for value in a:
            if value not in found:
                yield value
                found.append(value)
>>> list(unique(a))
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

But still, this is not really a good solution, and you should really just use `set` instead, as it will also give you further methods to work with that set once its created (e.g. a quick check for containedness).

> I'm also required to get the answer just by inputting `unique(a)`

In that case, just remove the `yield value` from your function, and return the `found` list at the end of it.

Comment: As for using a `list` instead of a `set`, of course a list works with unhashable types too, e.g. other lists, whereas a set doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known classic:

```
>>> def unique(xs):
...     seen = set()
...     seen_add = seen.add
...     return [x for x in xs if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]
...
>>> unique([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is `list(set(a)`

```
def unique(a):
  return list(set(a))
```

Now, coming to to your question. `yield` returns a generator that you must iterator over and not print. So if you have a function, which has a `yield` in it, iterate over like like `for return_value from function_that_yields():`

There are more problems with your question. You have not defined `found` and then you indexing value which may not be a container.

Comment: Mind you that this will destroy the original order.

Comment: im required to have the function named as "unique".

Comment: yep, the unique_everseen recipe from itertools retains original order

Comment: NullUserException - not sure if that was OP requirement.

Comment: @user1730056 - and just return this from the unique function. I shall edit the answer.